# Which docker image contains CLIs for both firebase and gcloud?

Tags: firebase, docker, gitlab-ci, gcloud

My .gitlab-ci.yml needs to call not only the [`gcloud` cli](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) but also [`firebase` cli](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli).

The [`image: google/cloud-sdk:latest`](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/) allows me to call the [`gcloud` cli](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) but not the [`firebase` cli](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli).

The [`image: devillex/docker-firebase`](https://hub.docker.com/r/devillex/docker-firebase) allows me to call the [`firebase` cli](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) but not the  [`gcloud` cli](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install).

I've tried installing the firebase CLI by following [firebase's CI/CD instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#mac-linux-auto-script) but I got an error about permissions which seemingly required `sudo`.  However, gitlab doesn't even offer `sudo`, not surprisingly.

I've tried searching the stackoverflow and hub.docker.com but I can't find an image that offers both CLIs.  Do you know of one that offers both?

Is there somewhere else I can search or some way to search differently (e.g. are certain keywords helpful in searching for a docker image)?

If I wanted to try to combine [`image: google/cloud-sdk:latest`](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/) and [`image: devillex/docker-firebase`](https://hub.docker.com/r/devillex/docker-firebase) into one image, how would I do that?  What's the first step?  I've never made a Docker image let alone tried to merge two existing ones.

Comment: You can't merge two images.  Usually the best thing to do here is to pick one of the images, figure out which Linux distribution it's based on, and use the package manager (`apk` for Alpine, or `apt-get` for Debian/Ubuntu) to install the other component.

Comment: There's a Cloud Build (a Google service) community developed (!) builder that includes Firebase CLI (not Cloud SDK). Because it's a community-developed solution and, because it's open-source, you can have some confidence that it's a good image and you can verify what it does. Be careful using arbitrary containers. Link: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase#using_the_firebase_community_builder

Comment: It's possible that you could build a script for Gitlab that uses two distinct images (Cloud SDK and Firebase) without needing to conbine them into one. If you can use the existing images as-is, you'll also avoid having to create and maintain your own image.

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin that (build a script for Gitlab that uses two distinct images) is actually what I've done as a workaround.  It works well but I'd love to simplify it.

Comment: @DavidMaze I could try using `image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine`, which is presumably based on Alpine.  Then I could use `apk`, right?  But is there an `apk` registry I can search for the command to install the firebase CLI?  There are some non-apk instructions at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#mac-linux-auto-script but they did not work on gitlab.  They failed because they needed sudo but sudo is not allowed on gitlab.

Comment: You could probably just add the binary to the `gcloud` image. But, be mindful that in your goal of simplification, you'll then need to ensure that every time either `gcloud` or Firebase CLIs change, you'll need to regenerate the image; I'm unsure whether it is simpler.

Comment: Related feature request at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1644

Answer (score 2):

You can base your docker image on google/cloud-sdk:alpine, and then install npm and use it to install firebase tools:

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk:alpine AS base

RUN apk add --update npm
RUN npm install -g firebase-tools
```